# Shiny: Title of the graph only for its downloaded pdf version

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to add the title to the graph only to downloaded pdf version of it? I would not like it to appear in shiny, just only when the user downloads the plot and opens it as pdf?

Simple code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataInput<-reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))  return(NULL)
    data<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, fileEncoding="UTF-16", sep="\t")
    data$date<-ymd(data$StartDate)
    data$date2<-format(data$date,"%b %y")
  })

  plotInput<-function(){
    data <- dataInput()
    ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=Queries, group=Category, color=Category))+geom_line(size=1.5)

  }

  output$plot <- renderPlot({plotInput()})

  output$foo <- downloadHandler(
    filename ="graph.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      pdf(file, width=12, height=6.3)
      print(plotInput())
            dev.off()
    })
})
})
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `plotInput()` returns a `ggplot` object, so you can just add the title using `ggtitle` to it in your `downloadHandler`:

```
output$foo <- downloadHandler(
            filename ="graph.pdf",
            content = function(file) {
                    pdf(file, width=12, height=6.3)
                    print(plotInput()+ggtitle('Title'))
                    dev.off()
            })
```